# In Perforce, I'm trying to do the merge, it has some conflicts. How to see the conflict files in command line or GUI

Tags: perforce

In Perforce, I'm trying to do the merge, it has some conflicts and and created pending change list. Pending has more than 10000 files. Because of the long list of files they are are not visible in GUI. How to see the conflict files in GUI or command line?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve non-conflicting files from the command line, do:

```
p4 resolve -am
```

After you've done that, you can resolve remaining files with:

```
p4 resolve
```

Or just get a list of the remaining (conflicted) files with:

```
p4 resolve -n
```

http://forums.perforce.com/index.php?/topic/5125-how-to-see-the-conflits-on-pending-change-list-during-merge/#entry20967